# Exception while creating TileConfigurer Bean SpringMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are using spring mvc with java configuration.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.anonymous"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${webCachePeriod}")
    private int cachePeriod;
    @Value("${maxUploadSize}")
    private long maxUploadSize;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(cachePeriod);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
                .setCachePeriod(cachePeriod);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }

    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false)
                .configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false)
                .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
                .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/views/tiles.xml"});
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadSize);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

While deploying the war we are getting the exception.
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [com/expedia/risk/cm/config/WebConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No URL for ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/tiles.xml]

Please see what is the problem with this thing, I tried but this looks okay to me.

Comment: Please show the content of the `/WEB-INF/views/tiles.xml`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YEkF4UFm

Comment: Take a look,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459740/error-no-url-for-servletcontext-resource-when-running-spring-integrated-test,may help you

Comment: please check the pastebin link

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't worked still the same exception